# Challenge on Some Language and PDA

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar, regular-language, turing-machines

Suppose We have Some language as follows:

$L_1=\{w^* | w=x \text{ and } x \in \Sigma^*\}$

$L_2=\{ww^R ww^R | w \in ( \Sigma  + \Sigma)^*\}$

$L_3=\{w | w=xy, x,y \in \Sigma^*, y \text{ is a substring of } x\}$

1) there is a PDA (push down automata) that accept $L_2 \cap L_3$

2) there is a PDA (push down automata) that accept $L_2 \cup L_3$

3) there is a PDA (push down automata) that accept $L_1 \cap L_3$

4) there is a PDA (push down automata) that accept $L_1 \cup L_2$

I read in some sites that:

(a) is false, and we can say 3 and 4 are wrong because we have no language that is not closed under union but closed under intersection.

I read a lot of material for finding the answer of this question mentioned by Prof. M. Farshchi on Entrance Exam in 2012, but I failed. I need some one to help me with a bit detail for each one. Thanks.

Comment: We are not going to do your homework (or help you find answers to an entrance exam etc.) unless you make some effort yourself first. Try to explain what you did so far and where you are stuck, then we can give you a little hint starting from there.

Comment: For example can you prove which one of the languages $L_1$, $L_2$ and $L_3$ are recognized by a PDA? If you have this you can think about how to get intersections or unions of those languages (there are general "closure" results for the class of context free languages). Also it would be a good thing to identify the intersections and unions of those languages first to see if they have a special (simple) structure which would make it easier to come up with a PDA accepting them or proving no such PDA exists.

Comment: Dear @MHS, i think, For c) and d) about union and intersection of two regular language, so c and d is regular and there is PDA. my problem is about (a) and (b) if my thought is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $L_2 \cap L_3 = L_2 \cap \Sigma^* = L_2$
2. $L_2 \cup L_3 = L_2 \cup \Sigma^* = \Sigma^*$
3. $L_1 \cap L_3 = \Sigma^* \cap \Sigma^* = \Sigma^*$
4. $L_1 \cup L_2 = \Sigma^* \cup L_2 = \Sigma^*$